# How to assign a conditional value to a key based on another of its properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

[image: My Problem]

I'm wondering how I can assign a value to a key that depends on another key inside that same object. In this case I want to say if animal has owner it is NOT food but if it does not have an owner it IS food. So in my example the object animal should evaluate to true and animal2 should evaluate to false but they don't.

```
> I have tried isFood: animal.owner ? false: true 
> I have tried isFood: animal.hasOwnProperty("owner") ? false: true
> I have tried isFood: "owner" in animal ? false: true
> I have tried isFood: this.owner ? false: true
```

```
interface personInterface {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    isMember: boolean
};
interface animalInterface<T> {
    owner?: T,
    sound: string,
    species: string,
    isFood: boolean
}

let person: personInterface;

person = {
    name: "justin",
    age: 30,
    isMember: true
}

let animal: animalInterface<personInterface>;
let animal2: animalInterface<personInterface>;

animal = {
    owner: {...person},
    sound: "Woof",
    species: "Dog",
    isFood: this.owner ? false: true
}

animal2 = {
    sound: "Woof",
    species: "Dog",
    isFood: this.owner ? false: true 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` may vary depending upon where it is used, inside a function or globally. In order to refer the current object and still access the key as a property, you can use `get` accessor like below. You can read more about `get` accessor [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```
animal = {
    owner: { ...person },
    sound: "Woof",
    species: "Dog",
    get isFood() {
        // Here this refers to current object
        return this.owner ? false : true
    }
}

animal2 = {
    sound: "Woof",
    species: "Dog",
    get isFood() {
        return this.owner ? false : true
    }
}

console.log(animal.isFood);
console.log(animal2.isFood);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve it, you need to use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions):

```js
interface PersonInterface {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    isMember: boolean
};

interface AnimalInterfaceBase<T> {
    owner?: T,
    sound: string,
    species: string,
    isFood: boolean
}

type WithOwner<T> = {
    owner: T,
    sound: string,
    species: string,
    isFood: false
}

type WithoutOwner = {
    sound: string,
    species: string,
    isFood: true
}


type AnimalInterface<T> = WithOwner<T> | WithoutOwner


let person: PersonInterface;

person = {
    name: "justin",
    age: 30,
    isMember: true
}

let animal: AnimalInterface<PersonInterface>;
let animal2: AnimalInterface<PersonInterface>;

animal = {
    owner: person,
    sound: "Woof",
    species: "Dog",
    isFood: false
}

animal2 = {
    owner: person, // expected error
    sound: "Woof",
    species: "Dog",
    isFood: true
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsQElzTxLIDeAUMpciHALYQBcyGYUoA5gDQVVzuPUArrQBG0blWTAMAWQijoTEViwAbCHBBkAvgG4yZUJFiIUAQRDBacVfmNEIAITgYIAHgAqAPlI9KWAHcQaAB%20Jg8JKmxBEAATJhY2EC4-ZgAHCARgCAwE1g5IymkAMRV45GU1DS1tAzAATwzkAHVgMAALAHkg6E8fAF5fSUDgqHDC5iwY8sSC1IwMrJy8pJTJErKmeFVXHTrGlFaOqbBu0eRB8klouJW568Xs3OZ85ImNrHLWQQg9-aaLFYbHZCKY%20hcWm0uj0oOCAD6Q46CU4wgxkdRgZAZKDYEBMdA4nAgkxIfRkbG4iFXKg0ehMABEACtBCxQPSJnwBABmAAM71k8jEY2Q31%20tXREExmiBqiYgOstgIJPcBNxxIcXn0GOQ0oVACY5ZYFeqwaqiUqNWTdTYqakRoosZgcBMbuV6c0VDB2fNHstkPSACJYdje9YYUqfLY2Xbi62qPW24YwpgU53IAD06eQEAAHotILFs1AoFgoPMprd-R6sF6Xb7noHg6GqB8vlAfjogA)

P.S. It is conventional to capitalize interface names.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tagged union types in this case. Basically you create two interfaces and discern them by a property, in your case `isFood`:

```js
interface BaseAnimalInterface {
    sound: string;
    species: string;
    isFood: boolean;
}

interface AnimalInterface extends BaseAnimalInterface {
    isFood: true;
}

interface PetInterface<T = PersonInterface> extends BaseAnimalInterface {
    owner: T;
    isFood: false;
}

type AnimalType = AnimalInterface | PetInterface;
```

Then, if you check into that property on an `if/switch` statement you'll get the proper type:

```js
function playSound(animal: AnimalType): void {
    if (animal.isFood) {
        // Casted automatically to `AnimalInterface`
    } else {
        // Casted automatically to `PetInterface`
    }
}
```

[Full example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsQElzTxLIDeAUMpciHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNwVVzuPUArrQBG0blWTAMAWQijoTEViwAbCHBDcAvmTKhIsRCgBCcDBACCIYLTir8hoinKTsgkABMmLNiC48lBgADhAIwBAYPqwcElTSAGIq3sjKahpaZLr6BEbE1rb2joTGyBAAHpBeGMhmFgV2DrnOpIFSGElYKayCEDp6BiXE6GDFeRAAPAAqyAC8aJg4Y84AfGWVENW15lY2jculrlRYAO4gishTcZSJyUzwqhb9ZGAAnqHIDfZT7yjzX00nKUAD4AApGByQ3DICBwLGQoSg2BATHQSKWzVK8yOlBo9CYACIAFaCFigAkAGjafAEAGYAAxUyTSOQKKBMHoQLLQ2EgeGhMBMAE-D7Ytqnc7s0gAOlliOR2iZVHcXkJAHUVDBKW0QmEIlFkASACJYdja5kdO7IB4WKnaHlwsDIE7AVQpYW-OatNxYDwpAkarBapVBULhSKEk1mkPtTrdKC9bl6GAeBBgYA4BGqOCvADKvq8AApNIVVEK9t9fgBKJgANywwE83viMGQxYrqmlty6VebkkoAHoB8gAMLmSBNuCCMBYOzphD2VSvZAz5AAAwBkIga7a2jKjxcbUkQ9H44gk+ns7g88Xy9Xa4hmKQO8kum0QA)